# how to connect sqLite database to netbeans

Tags: java, database, sqlite, netbeans

I want to create some applications in Java netbeans using sqLite manager. i had done the following steps.

1. I have done plugin to Mozilla Firefox a sqLite-manger database
2. I have create database calling  "mydb".
3. I have create a table with 2 values fname , lname.
4. I got mydb.sqlite file.
5. In netbeans library i have add jar file calling sqlite-jdbc 3.7.2 jar
6. then i copy the file  mydb.sqlite from the folder and paste into netbeans project folder .

   7. I want to connect with my project calling "test" in netbeans.

how to connect with netbeans application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm

Most important part is jdbc url to create connection:

```
jdbc:sqlite:mydb.sqlite
```

This url assumes that test.db located in same directory, u application starts from. But u can put path to certain db.

For example:

```
jdbc:sqlite:c:/temp/sqlite/mydb.sqlite
```

If u distribute u application when there u manage some initialization. Actually u have to set environment for u application before start. Let's say u have good working application in netbeans and u copy application to another machine. 
Configure environment for application to make it same as actual working application instance in netbeans. Question u should think about

- What path to database to use relative or absolute?
- Where database location on filesystem (absolute path to database)?
- Where directory from which application starts (relative path to database)?

Useful information:

- jdbc driver will create database mysql.sqlite if it doesn't exists (path to directory *"c:/temp/sqlite"* should be real) and after u can recreate necessary structure of database.
- u can use System Properties https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html especially *user.dir* and *user.home* to set predefined location of u database (create database in there or copy existing database file)

Comment: after that when i run the program it must sucess in my system. but when i gives this application  may it show the error in database connection while providing this "jdbc:sqlite:c:/temp/sqlite/mydb.sqlite" ?

Comment: If database exists meas path c:/temp/sqlite/mydb.sqlite real, then error will not happen.